# Why does 1.send(:hour) return 3600 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In my n00bish understanding, 1 is class Fixnum.

```
puts 1.class.name
```

`send()` allows you to call a method within the class.  So `1.send()` should call a method of class `Fixnum`.

Finally, what's in the parenthesis specifies which method to call.  In this case, I would be calling the hour method of the Fixnum class.

But there is no "hour" method of `Fixnum`, as least from what I can see [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html).  Instead, it seems to take the Fixnum object and multiply by the number of seconds in an hour to give the number of seconds in [object] number of :hours.  And...I don't follow - how do you think about why this works the way it does?

Comment: are you on `irb` or `rails console`

Comment: because as of `ruby 2.3.3` I am getting `NoMethodError: undefined method `hour' for 1:Fixnum` for both syntax `1.hour` and `1.send(:hour)`

Comment: `1.method(:hour) => #NameError: undefined method 'hour' for class 'Integer'` shows that Ruby does not have an `Integer` (or `Fixnum`) instance method `hour`. As pointed out in the answers, that is a Rails method, so you need to add a Rails tag.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced on (pure) Ruby.

Comment: In case you are coming to Ruby from less dynamic languages - in Ruby, anyone can extend/change the functionality of anything (with some exceptions), including core classes. This is a case of Rails doing this for numbers.

Comment: Btw I don't know why this question got downvoted so much. It might be obvious for someone in the Ruby community, but not so much for someone coming to it. The question is clearly stated and adequately structured. It also shows that OP put the effort to read the documentation. It's not unclear, typographical error or low quality.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby has a very flexible run-time environment where classes and objects can have methods added or removed at any time for any reason by any bit of code in the program.

This ability to mutate existing classes and add in new functionality is called "monkey patching", though if done more formally it's usually described as "core extensions", that is, extensions to core Ruby classes. Rails has a *lot* of these and `hours` is one of them.

Looking in the class documentation is not necessarily the most reliable way of finding out where a method is coming from. In most cases the best approach is to simply ask, as Ruby does have great support for *reflection*, where code can interrogate code about things:

```
1.method(:hours)
```

That returns a [Method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Method.html) object that describes the method in question. One of the most useful parts of that is this:

```
1.method(:hours).source_location
```

That tells you where the method's defined. It'll lead you to something like `active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb` which means this is an ActiveSupport thing, which it is. These extensions are [documented on the Rails site](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html) if you're curious about the details.

Keep in mind a simple value like `1` gets methods from *all* of its ancestor classes, *plus* any module extensions applied to it (mix-ins) as well as any other things that have been added on in a more ad-hoc fashion.

If you ask where that gets methods from:

```
1.class.ancestors
```

That's an awfully long list in modern Rails.

Comment: There's also a chapter about [Active Support Core Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) in the Rails Guides.

Answer (score 4):

This is rails extension (read: monkeypatch) for [`Numeric`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-hour) class.

Answer (score 1):

Rails has a numeric monkey patch available which will convert units like 1.hour, 1.minute, or even 1.day to a format friendly for working with the Ruby class of Time.

So without this numeric helper, something like this:

```
snapshot_of_time = Time.now

snapshot_of_time + 1
# => Just returns the time when the variable was defined, plus 1 second. 
# To move it forward an hour, I'd have to remember an hour was 3600 seconds.
```

Whereas, with this Numeric class method added:

```
snapshot_of_time = Time.now

snapshot_of_time + 1.hour
# => Predictably provides you with a time that's 1 hour in the future
# of your snapshot!
```

Simply put, you're either running some sort of method extension in ruby, or in a rails console. This helper method is not included in Ruby by default as of version 2.4.0